# Kotlin plug-in adds kotlin-stdlib by default

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

In many android projects, I observed this kotin stdlib dependency being added in the Gradle files. I also observed `kotlin` and `kotlin-android` plugin also adds it by default.

I am assuming adding it manually can be avoided? Or is there a downside to it?

```
org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:${versions.kotlin}
```

Also, I believe

```
android {
  ...
  compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  }
  kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = "1.8"
  }
}
```

`compileOptions` can be safely dropped from 100% kotlin application.

Using `kotlinOptions.jvmTarget="11"` is there a downside to it, in terms of byte-code generation and byte-code compatibility with other jdk versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am assuming adding it manually can be avoided? Or is there a
> downside to it?

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/gradle.html#dependency-on-the-standard-library

There's no downside to it, if you want to add it manually and donot want it to be downloaded by the plugin - set this plugin `kotlin.stdlib.default.dependency=false` property false in `gradle.properties` file.

> Using kotlinOptions.jvmTarget="11" is there a downside to it, in terms
> of byte-code generation and byte-code compatibility with other jdk
> versions.

It require `AGP 7.0+` to desugar apps for API levels 29 and earlier, while targeting `jvmVersion` to `8` only requires AGP 3.0+.

Otherwise, byte-code is same.

> compileOptions can be safely dropped from 100% kotlin application.

Android projects are not 100% Kotlin, there are generated files like BuildConfig.java.

`compileOptions` should be there, it can be avoided in 100% Kotlin module.